# Docker Compose to only start the containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have 4 containers that i have created via 'docker create' and 'docker run' command. currently i start the containers one by one using below commands as they have dependency:

docker start a
docker start b
docker start c
docker start d

can i only start the containers using docker-compose or do i need to build also using docker compose first.
I am using direct solution from the GIT so converting everything to docker-compose will be lot of effort, so wanted to confirm the same.
I tried using docker compose up -d with specifying one of the container as service in the docker-compose.yaml file but it failed calling out for the dependent container volume declaration.

Answer (score 0):

`docker-compose up` doesn't build containers, it just starts them.

Replace `build` in your compose file with `image` if you have already built the images and just run them using the mentioned command. If you have dependencies between your containers/services, you can use `depends_on` to tell docker which containers/services should be started before the one that depends on them.

your docker compose-file could look something like this

```
...
services:
  service_a:
    image: a
    ...
  service_b:
    image: b
    depends_on:
      - service_a
    ...
  service_c:
    image: c
    depends_on:
      - service_b
    ...
  service_d:
    image: d
    depends_on:
      - service_c
    ...
```

Comment: I tried the same but its trying to create the container also and failing with below error. I want to only start the already created container.

Comment: ERROR: for racnode-cman  Cannot create container for service client-cman: Conflict. The container name "/racnode-cman" is already in use by container "917da93d8822f11a9450c10154ecb92fe244370ad841e11b82a0cd56013ac0ed". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.

ERROR: for client-cman  Cannot create container for service client-cman: Conflict. The container name "/racnode-cman" is already in use by container "917da93d8822f11a9450c10154ecb92fe244370ad841e11b82a0cd56013ac0ed". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.

Comment: You should remove the container that is causing the name conflict and start it using docker compose. You don't need to build a new image but you should let the compose start its own instance of the container.

Comment: ok , so the new instance of container will be created, we can not use docker-compose to only start the containers created by different method.